# How to disable default right click menu of browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js, cross-browser

In my Application,in particular `div`,I want to show custom right click menu with options instead of default browser menu.

I tried with following code.

```
events: {
   "contextmenu #navContainer":"rightClickTest"
},
rightClickTest:function(event){
 if (event.button == 2){
   alert("Right Click is not possible Here !")
  }
}
```

we am using `backbone.js` for my Application.Event is working fine but the problem is after completion of event logic,default right click menu appearing as usually.

Note:

I want to disable default right click menu at particular div(`navContainer`) of my App.

How can I fix this.

Comment: @rajmathan Maybe you will be surprised, but it also has already an answer *there*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it..

```
rightClickTest:function(event){
  if (event.button == 2){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("Right Click is not possible Here !")
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I found the solution.But I forgot to post the answer. Anyhow thanks for your valuable answer.